# Unable to run python code on Visual Studio, crashes after Launching Debug Editor

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, crash

I was trying to get datetime.py working as one of the functions from it just didn't exist in my datetime.py file. In my datetime.py the fromiso() function is not present in the code.  To test it I opened a new VS project and tried compiling a small code snippet that would only invoke the missing function from datetime after import, and that's when I first encountered this problem. I'm not sure if this is related to this problem, but this is the last thing I was doing.

When running the code it will flash console quickly before opening "Launching debug adapter" window, this will prevent me from doing anything for maybe 10s and then will return to the starting point having neither executed my code nor opened the debugger.

[image]

Now I am unable to run any program whatsoever, running with either `ctr`+`f5` or `fn`+`f5` leads to same glitch. I have not touched anything in the VS settings prior. I have tried powercycling just for a good measure, but sadly that didn't fix anything. Running as admin yields same result.